# incompatible types when assigning to type 'char *[12]' from type 'int'

Tags: c, memory, malloc

I have an array of `char*`

```
#define SEASRCH_ENGINES_QUEUE_MAX_SIZE  12
static char* searchEnginesNamesQueue[SEASRCH_ENGINES_QUEUE_MAX_SIZE];
```

I want to nullify it after I free its memory:

`searchEnginesNamesQueue = NULL;`

but I get this error:

`incompatible types when assigning to type 'char *[12]' from type 'int'`

Comment: Arrays are not assignable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is an array, and arrays cannot be assigned to.

Also, you cannot "free its memory", arrays cannot be freed, you can only free dynamically allocated ("heap") memory.

If you mean you have had heap memory pointers stored *in* the array, which have then been freed, you must set each pointer in the array to `NULL`:

```
for(int i = 0;
    i < sizeof searchEnginesNamesQueue / sizeof *searchEnginesNamesQueue;
    ++i)
{
  searchEnginesNamesQueue[i] = NULL;
}
```

The loop can easily be written without braces, but I had to put the header on multiple lines to avoid horizontal scrolling.

Note nifty use of `sizeof` to have the compiler compute the loop boundary.

Comment: why not `free(searchEnginesNamesQueue[i])`? so if I want to have a flag that the pointers in the array are freed, I have to add boolean? I have thought to use `array = NULL` but this is not an option

Answer (score 1):

Basically NULL is an integer and your searchEnginesNamesQueue is an array of character pointer. you just can't assign it like that. Try value of char pointer to NULL, maybe like this *char = NULL.

Comment: I have tried `searchEnginesNamesQueue = (char *)NULL;` unsuccessfully

Comment: try *searchEnginesNamesQueue = NULL